# What is the order of the function type : int -> int -> int -> int

Tags: sml

What is the order of the function type : **int -> int -> int -> int**?

I don't really understand what the question is asking or where to begin figuring out the answer. I can't seem to find any helpful pages on sml anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, ML is a functional language, so if you're short on SML specific material, you should still be able to glean useful information from any functional language references.  Reading up about first order and higher order functions should help.  However this is not really an ML (or SML) question, but a functional programming question.

**With the caveat that my functional knowledge is possibly rusty:**

A function is first order if its arguments and result value is both "data", that is, not other functions.  A function is higher-order if it takes another function as a parameter or returns a function as a parameter.

The order of a higher order function then is defined as one more than the order of either its parameters or return value.

The function type **int -> int** describes a function that takes an int and outputs an int.  This is therefore a first order function, with order 1.

The function type **int -> int -> int** describes a function that takes an int, and outputs *(a function that takes an int and outputs an int)*, e.g. we can rewrite

```
int -> int -> int
```

as

```
int -> (int -> int)
```

So the output of the function that takes an int is another (first order) function like I described previously.

Now, we know that the order of the parameter (int) is 1 (it's just data, not a function), and the order of the *output* (e.g. a first order function int -> int) is also 1, therefore the order of the whole function type **int -> int -> int** is therefore 1+1, e.g. 2.

By a similar extension it follows that the order of the function type

```
int -> int -> int -> int
```

is 3.